# Ways to undo the commits of 2 months ago in Git after push the commits?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, undo

I saw the solutions on undo the **last / last x commits** in Git.
What I want to know is how to undo the commits that are pushed **2 months ago**. I want to undo just the commits in the middle of the commits, but want to keep the other commits.

for example:

```
commit 1  ----  2 mins ago
commit 2  ----  1 day ago
....
commit 105  ---  2 months ago
commit 106  ---  2 months ago
commit 107  ---  3 months ago
....
```

In the example, I want to reverse **commits 105 and 106**, but keep the other commits as they are.

Comment: What do you mean by "undo"? Do you want to remove these commits from your history? Or do you want to just reverse the changes that these commits made? Are these commits on your main branch or any other shared branch?

Comment: Let's assume that those are on my main branch.

Comment: if I want to just reverse the changes that those commits made?

Comment: I don't think it's problem if we want to reverse or remove it. The main focus is how to manage the old commits without affecting the other commits.

Comment: The easiest is probably reversing the changes from the commits with `git revert`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, what do you think about the answers below? I don't want to break anything since any of the answers might not work as expected.

Comment: Fortunately, almost all actions you take with git are reversable. So try something and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

`git revert` will create a new commit that undoes the changes that made in the target commit.  So in your example, you would run `git revert 105 106` and this will make 2 new commits that remove the changes that were made in those commits.

If you only wanted to undo the changes from only one file in the those commits, you can do `git reset HEAD~2` (This assumes that you have 2 reverted commits).  Then you can `git checkout` the files that you don't want to have the changes undone.  Once that is done, you can `git add` and `git commit` to undo the changes to only the specific files.

Comment: if I do` git reset HEAD~2`, it will revert the most recent 2 commits. no?

Comment: `reset` will not revert but remove the commits and leave the changes which you will be able to see with `git status`

Answer (score 1):

#### You have two options:

## [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the commits

> This will create new commits on top of the current commits removing the changes applied in commits 105 and 106 and the commits will still be present in the git log.

```bash
git revert 106 105
```

---

## drop the commits with [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

> This will completely remove the commits from the history as they have never existed, but all of the following commits will be re-applied on top of commit 104 and they'll have different hashes

```bash
git rebase 105~1 --interactive
```

Git will open your [$EDITOR](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$EDITOR_variable) with list of commits followed by a long comment with all of the options

```
pick 105 Commit message
pick 106 Commit message
pick 107 Commit message
pick 108 Commit message

# Rebase 7fd6a37..9141cc2 onto 7fd6a37 (4 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup [-C | -c] <commit> = like "squash" but keep only the previous
#                    commit's log message, unless -C is used, in which case
#                    keep only this commit's message; -c is same as -C but
#                    opens the editor
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
#         create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
#         message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
#         specified); use -c <commit> to reword the commit message
# u, update-ref <ref> = track a placeholder for the <ref> to be updated
#                       to this position in the new commits. The <ref> is
#                       updated at the end of the rebase
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

to remove the commits you can either change `pick` top `drop` on the first two lines, or delete the first two lines.

> If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.

Once saving the opened file and exiting the [$EDITOR](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$EDITOR_variable) git will remove the commits and re-apply the rest on top. Then you should [force push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force) the changes (assuming you have the privileges, as it's probably a [protected branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/about-protected-branches))

---

*presuming the commit numbers are their hashes*