# CSS for two button range slider

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend, input-type-range

I want to create a two button slider and apply styles to the same. I have created slider but not able to style the slider.

Here is what I require

[image: Accepted Output]

---

Here is what I have done

[image: My output]

I am not able to style slider using css

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <input type="range">
  <input type="range">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect this to work. Each slider control will only be able to traverse its own slider. See [HTML slider with two inputs possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753946/html5-slider-with-two-inputs-possible). The [2022 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70561454/1264804) may be your best bet.

Comment: Why two inputs? That's wrong on so many levels... Why would you want to orevent someone go beyound a certain range? Is this on purpose? If so... why?

Comment: It can definitely be done by adding some CSS. check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out. hope this helps you. You can adjust anything you want.
I am adding a screenshot of it.
[image]

And here's the full code.

```css
.range_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 35% auto;
}

.sliders_control {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.form_control {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #635a5a;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #C6C6C6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #C6C6C6;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #387bbe, 0 0 9px #387bbe;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #387bbe, 0 0 9px #387bbe;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f79847;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#fromSlider {
  height: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="range_container">
  <div class="sliders_control">
    <input id="fromSlider" type="range" value="10" min="0" max="100" />
    <input id="toSlider" type="range" value="40" min="0" max="100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can see exactly what you want. please kindly click "**Run code snippet**" in my answer. happy to help you.  

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot I have been trying this for the whole day. You made my day thanks a lot @JShobbyist

Comment: @VaibhavMore, Love to hear that. I am really happy to help.  :)   accept my answer?

Comment: Do you have some time to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74827402/14912225)?