# How to fix the issue with the referencing static files in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, reference

This is similar to [relative path to CSS file [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621324/relative-path-to-css-file). but it's about `Java web application` and what I am talking about is `.NET`. They're the same?

I am having an issue with **ASP.NET core**. In the `Index.cshtml`, there are some codes, which include CSS static files:

```
...
<link href="~/css/features.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

The problem is that I am getting `404 error` on the web page. Seems like the path is not correct in the code. see the attached screenshots:
[image]

How can I resolve this? Why it causes an issue?

FYI: I am attaching the screenshots of the folder structure and code snippets.
[image]

[image]

Comment: @user09938  thanks for your suggestion, but the link to "**relative path to CSS file**" is about `JAVA`. The question I am asking is about `asp.net` core.

Comment: Your first image is very unclear. What URL is it trying to load?

Comment: Your certainly isn't a duplicate of that Java question.  But what are you using `~` to represent?  In asp.net `~/` represents the root directory of the application, see [Slash (/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6424114).  Also, what versions are you using?  Can you share a [mcve] that is clearer that your screen shots?  [Tilde Slash Paths Not Working in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10853316) may be relevant.

Comment: @dbc, thanks for your comment. The issue is resolved. The article you attached is exactly what I was looking for. Please write your answer here, and I will accept it.   :)  thank you so much.

Comment: Which article?  "Tilde Slash Paths Not Working in MVC 4" or "Slash (/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path."

Comment: "Slash (/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path.".   : )

Comment: I've removed `~` from the code and it worked well.  

Comment: @dbc, are you familiar with git? if so, would you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74827402/14912225) too? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding this answer since [dbc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) didn't want to leave the answer here even though I asked him to leave an answer.
The solution is to remove `~` from the code. He provided a very helpful answer - [Slash (/) vs tilde slash (~/) in style sheet path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6424114) and it was a topic regarding `ASP.NET` and  exactly what I was looking for. I resolved the issue. : )